# Is additional encryption required on iOS when storing files with .completeFileProtection?

Tags: ios, swift, encryption

On iOS, if a file is stored using `.completeFileProtection` it is encrypted by the OS and only accessible when the device is unlocked according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files).

In another app I looked at, the developers had encrypted all files manually and then stored the symmetric key in the device keychain.

I'm wondering if there really is any security benefit from doing that rather than using the built in `.completeFileProtection`? Or would it ever make sense to do both?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, with an additional encryption, files will *remain* encrypted even when device is **unlocked**.

Also, file will be decrypted *only* when app needs to read it. With this approach, the app could decrypt and read files even in background mode — if we don't change the level of data protection, since default is `NSFileProtectionCompleteUntilFirstUserAuthentication`.